# Does a TextChanged event fire if the text hasn't changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, compiler-optimization

I'm working on customizing (and fixing) a large application for a client which was purchased from another source. The code we ended up getting was most certainly NOT the actual code used in production by the source client. That being said, I ran into this today:

```
if (lblCurrentValueOfContractAmount.Text == "0.0")
   lblCurrentValueOfContractAmount.Text = "0.0";
```

And no, I'm not joking. My first inclination was to just remove it, then I started talking to another developer who mentioned that there might be some clandestine stuff going on here, like somebody subscribed to the label's text being changed, etc. Honestly I'm not that concerned about it, so I'm just going to leave it in. However, this brings me to my question:

Let's assume that there *is* someone subscribed to `TextChanged`, for example. If the text doesn't actually change, would the compiler optimize that whole statement away? Would the event actually fire?

Comment: Is the == in the second line supposed to be a single = ?

Comment: ah, yes, sorry. edited.

Comment: Wouldn't it take less than five minutes to check yourself? New Winform -> add textbox -> set breakpoint in text changed event -> from somewhere else, call `textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text;`

Comment: I would think raising the text changed event manually would be more effective and reliant. What type is lblCurrentValueOfContractAmount?

Comment: @RufusL I was hoping to get some info on what the compiler would do with it... I could check myself, but that wouldn't tell me why the compiler did what it did, if there were some conditions where it would fire and some where it wouldn't, etc... Looking for someone with more knowledge to learn from rather than just seeing if it fires in this specific case or not.

Comment: Look up the class of that variable on http://referencesource.microsoft.com/  and see what the implementation is

Comment: The compiler isn't going to do anything here because a property set is not like setting a field. Whether there is a side effect, you'll have to trace the code to see beyond what you've posted here.

Comment: @DrewJordan Sure, I understand. Not trying to be rude, but it appears that you haven't even checked to see whether or not setting the value to the existing value triggers the event (which would answer your second question), nor read the documentation on the event (which states that it occurs when the Text property value changes). This answers your first question - that it has nothing to do with the compiler, but how the class implementation of the event is written. It does not send a TextChanged event notification unless the `value` being set is different than the existing value.

Comment: @RufusL np, and you're right, I didn't even think to look at the documentation, just came here first out of habit. Seems like you're right, it doesn't change, now that I have checked the docs where Steve Mitcham pointed me to. Next time I'll try to remember to go check documentation first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a Winforms Label (or other Control derived class), the code will not fire a change event and therefore that code has no side effects and can be removed.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9884211b7ff61817

```
        public virtual string Text {
        get { ... }

        set {
            if (value == null) {
                value = "";
            }

            if (value == Text) {
                return;
            }
            // omitted remainder
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler wouldn't optimize it away unless it could be proven to have no side-effects.  Whether it has side-effects is a matter of exactly what the `Text` property setter method does.  What that setter does is up to the writer of that method.  Good behavior would be to check whether the text has actually changed and only fire the `TextChanged` event if a real change has occurred.  But you can't just trust the original developer--time to do some testing of your own.  Hook the `TextChanged` event and see if it fires when you set, but don't actually change, the text.

Answer (score 0):

The event will not fire over and over.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This does not cause the event to continuously fire
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

I set the textbox initially to have the value "0.0" and then did this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "0.0";
}
```

This did not cause the TextChangedEvent to fire.